# Label in Bootstrap covers textboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm relatively new to having to actually style web pages and I'm having an issue with using Bootstrap. As shown in the bootply below, a simple page, using bootstrap columns and some custom styling, causes the labels to overlap the textboxes when the page is resized - for example, try narrowing the width of the page. What am I missing that is causing this behaviour?

http://www.bootply.com/ttuZZWim70

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to create a horizontal form, you will want to add the appropriate Bootstrap horizontal form classes. Examples can be found at [Horizontal Form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). You would want to structure your html similar to the following with `form-horizontal` class on the form element and each group of labels/inputs with `form-group`. You can adjust the `col-sm-*` as necessary to organize your layout. It's best practice to try to get your column definitions `col-*-*` to add up to 12. Two get two `form-group` to display on a single row, you can utilize something like `col-md-6` wrapped around each `form-group`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Long name test 1</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Test">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Long name test 1</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Test">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLdcnpe9/2/) showing an example. You will need to extend the results window to be able to see the elements side by side. The horizontal form elements take up quite a bit of room so I might recommend giving each their own separate line similar to example on bootstrap.

Let me know if that helps.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the below link.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykpr5/61/)

```html
<form class="well span12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <label>Long name test 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6">
        <label>Long name test 3</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6">
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <label>Long name test 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6">
        <label>Long name test 4</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6">
      </div>
    </div>        
</form>
```

Comment: Please note that `span6` is prior to Bootstrap version 3

Answer (score 0):

Copy this and paste in your code Dam sure it will work.

```
                        <div class="form-group field">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
```